# mysql query not executing in java but executing in my SQLYog

Tags: java, mysql, sql

can anyone please tell why the following update query which is working perfectly when executed directly from my SQLYog editor, but not executing from java. it is not giving any exception but not updating into the database.

this the update query

```
UPDATE hotel_tables SET hotel_tables.status='reserved' WHERE hotel_tables.section='pub' AND tableno='4' AND ('4' NOT IN (SELECT tableno FROM table_orders WHERE outlet='pub'))
```

**Java code**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    int update = new Dbhandler().update("UPDATE hotel_tables SET hotel_tables.status='reserved' WHERE hotel_tables.section='pub' AND tableno='4' AND ('4' NOT IN (SELECT tableno FROM table_orders WHERE outlet='pub'))");
}

public int update(String Query)throws Exception
{
    try
    {
        cn=getconn();
        stmt=(Statement) cn.createStatement();
        n=stmt.executeUpdate(Query);
        stmt.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw(e);
    }
    finally
    {
        cn.close();
    }
    return n;
}

public Connection getconn()
{
    try
    {
        Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
        String url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/kot?user=root&password=root";
        cn=(Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(url);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("DBHandler ERROR:"+e);
    }
    return cn;
}
```

Comment: Ive posted the java code.........

Comment: are you getting the value of update greater than 0?

Comment: i'm getting the value as 0.........but the same query is updating correctly when executed through SQLYog editor.....

Comment: just copy this in mysql and run **UPDATE hotel_tables SET hotel_tables.status='reserved' WHERE hotel_tables.section='pub' AND tableno='4' AND ('4' NOT IN (SELECT tableno FROM table_orders WHERE outlet='pub'))**

Comment: when executed directly its updating......but not updating through java

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40184/discussion-between-javabeginner-and-user2318483)

Answer (score 0):

This is how I used to do it before I switched to Spring's JdbcTemplate framework.  Maybe this will help.  It looks very similar to yours.

```
public static int runUpdate(String query, DataSource ds, Object... params) throws SQLException  {
    int rowsAffected = 0;
    Connection conn = null;
    PreparedStatement stmt = null;
    try {
        conn = ds.getConnection();
        stmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
        int paramCount = 1;
        for (Object param : params) {
            stmt.setObject(paramCount++, param);
        }
        rowsAffected = stmt.executeUpdate();
        conn.commit();
    } catch (SQLException sqle) {
        throw sqle;
        //log error
    } finally {
        closeConnections(conn, stmt, null);
    }
    return rowsAffected;
}
```

There are some subtle differences.  I do a commit, though autoCommit is the default.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:
    DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/kot","root","root");